How to create a Python program to display bingo numbers for my hearing-impaired grandfather
I am working on a project to assist my grandfather, who is gradually losing his hearing and enjoys attending bingo sessions. Due to his hearing impairment, he is no longer able to hear the numbers being called during the game. To address this, I am developing a program that listens for the bingo numbers and displays them on the screen. However, I am encountering a few challenges:
The program might capture sounds other than the bingo numbers. I need a way to filter the input to ensure that it only detects the numbers.
The audio capture quality could be improved, as sometimes my grandfather has difficulty hearing the numbers, especially in noisy environments.
Below is the code I have written so far:
import pyaudio
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
import json  # Import for handling the result as a JSON object

# Function to listen for numbers
def listen_for_number():
    # Path to the Vosk model
    model = Model("model/vosk-model")  # Change this path if it's different
    recognizer = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)

    # Initialize microphone
    mic = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = mic.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=4000)
    stream.start_stream()

    print("Listening...")

    while True:
        # Capture audio in chunks
        data = stream.read(4000)
        if recognizer.AcceptWaveform(data):
            result = recognizer.Result()

            try:
                # Convert the result to JSON
                result_json = json.loads(result)
                text = result_json.get("text", "")
                if text:
                    print(f"You said: {text}")
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                print("Error decoding the audio result.")
                continue

# Run the listening function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    listen_for_number()


I would greatly appreciate any guidance on:
How to filter out irrelevant sounds, ensuring the program only detects bingo numbers.
Suggestions for improving the audio capture quality, as my grandfather sometimes struggles to hear the numbers due to background noise.
Additionally, I am open to considering other programming languages if they may provide a better solution for this task.
Thank you for your time and assistance.
